# unable to implement search view in my custom list view

Tags: java, android

i googled and watched youtube but unable to implement it.
i found way to do it but i also have to change my custom list view code.
But i want to implement it in my custom list view.

there are harder one but i like this list view. its easy to implement.

```
package com.example.inventorymanagment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomListView extends AppCompatActivity {

static SQLiteDatabase sql;

static ListView lv;
SearchView sv;
static ArrayList midArr = new ArrayList();
static ArrayList mitemNameArr = new ArrayList();
static ArrayList msacPriceStockArr = new ArrayList();
static myAdapter mad;



public void show() {
    midArr.clear();
    mitemNameArr.clear();
    msacPriceStockArr.clear();
    mad = new myAdapter(this , midArr ,mitemNameArr ,msacPriceStockArr);

    Cursor c = sql.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM item_list", null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            midArr.add(c.getInt(0));
            mitemNameArr.add(c.getString(1));
            msacPriceStockArr.add("Sac/Hsn : "+c.getString(2) + "  "
                    + "Price : "+c.getInt(3) + "   "
                    + "Stock : "+c.getInt(4));
            //(id ,item_name , sac_hsn , price , stock)
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    lv.setAdapter(mad);
    c.close();

}

public void delete(int position){

   sql.execSQL("DELETE FROM item_list where ID = " + position + "");
    show();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate(R.menu.menu_items , menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.about:
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Credit")
                    .setMessage("THIS APP IS DEVELOPED BY MANJIT SAHA")
                    .setPositiveButton("Close" , null).show();

            return true;

        default:
            return false;
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_list_view);


    lv = findViewById(R.id.customListView);
    sv = findViewById(R.id.searchView);

    sql = this.openOrCreateDatabase("inventory", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    sql.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item_list (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            "item_name VARCHAR," +
            "sac_hsn VARCHAR," +
            "price INT," +
            "stock INT)");


    show();



    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , UpdateItems.class);
            i.putExtra("Id" , Integer.parseInt(midArr.get(position).toString()));
            startActivity(i);

          }
    });

    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            delete(Integer.parseInt(midArr.get(position).toString()));
            lv.setSelection(position);

            return true;
        }
    });


}


}


class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

Context context;
ArrayList ridArr = new ArrayList();
ArrayList ritemNameArr = new ArrayList();
ArrayList rsacPriceStockArr = new ArrayList();

myAdapter(Context c , ArrayList id , ArrayList name , ArrayList sps){
    super(c , R.layout.row  , R.id.idTv , id);

    this.context = c;
    this.ridArr = id;
    this.ritemNameArr = name;
    this.rsacPriceStockArr = sps;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row , parent , false);

    TextView idt = row.findViewById(R.id.idTv);
    TextView itemname = row.findViewById(R.id.itemNameRow);
    TextView sps = row.findViewById(R.id.spsRow);

    idt.setText(ridArr.get(position).toString());
    itemname.setText(ritemNameArr.get(position).toString());
    sps.setText(rsacPriceStockArr.get(position).toString());

    return row;
}


}
```

Please don't delete or say to try . i am trying since yesterday.
please implement it.

Answer (score 0):

i implemented it. but i wasn't able to implement it using adapters that filter adapter.
i was displaying data from sqlite. so, i directly get search data from sqlite.

```
 public void search(String searchText) {
        ArrayList localIdArr = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList localItemNameArrr = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList localSacPriceStockArrr = new ArrayList();

        myAdapter localMad = new myAdapter(getApplicationContext(), localIdArr, localItemNameArrr, localSacPriceStockArrr);
        Log.i("Query ", searchText);
        Cursor c = sql.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM item_list WHERE item_name LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'", null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                localIdArr.add(c.getInt(0));
                localItemNameArrr.add(c.getString(1));
                localSacPriceStockArrr.add("Sac/Hsn : " + c.getString(2) + "  "
                        + "Price : " + c.getInt(3) + "   "
                        + "Stock : " + c.getInt(4));
                //(id ,item_name , sac_hsn , price , stock)
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }


        lv.setAdapter(localMad);
        c.close();
       }
```

after that i call this function on searchView queryTextListener and passed the query argument..
and it works like butter as it should.